# how to find total number of pages of any document file in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to fetch the total number of pages of the file containing any extension like .xls,.pdf or .doc file.

I am able to fetch total number of pages of pdf file with code below,

```
NSString *pathToPdfDoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypdf" ofType:@"pdf"];    
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPdfDoc];   
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
```

Is there any way to find number of pages of files with extension other than .pdf

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really -- at least, not in a universal way.   The # of pages in any given document is entirely dependent upon how that document is interpreted by the owning application.   You might be able to do something tricksy with AppleScript, but that would assume that applications that can render said documents are all installed on the system.